# Animation Like : Bird Flying?[DONE]

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

**Qus :**

***What is the possible Solution for make the Animation and change the View Position simultaneously LIKE: Bird Flying ?***

**A arrow_anim.xml file for Animation :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow1" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow2" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow3" android:duration="1000" />
</animation-list>
```

**Code snippet for Animation :**

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_anim);
AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
anim.start();
```

**This is like standing Animation And I need to change Animation and their Position asa well as.**

*What class is helped me to acheive this bird functionality.*

**Edit 1 for the Code what I'm trying**

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.movie);
AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
anim.start();


TranslateAnimation trans = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,
                    TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 250, 0, 0,
                    TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 250);
trans.setDuration(0);


AnimationSet animationSet=new AnimationSet(true);
animationSet.addAnimation(trans);
imageView.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

But this not working simultaneously. If something is missing, suggest me to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that i know what you want, you can just `start()` your `AnimationDrawable` and then start translate animation for a `imageView` like:

```
View.startAnimation(Animation);
```

Comment: I need a solution but In the answer part , you are putting what you get.

Comment: have you got any solution/solution ?

Comment: as i said just call anim.start(); imageView.startAnimarion(translateAnimation)

Comment: when I tried this ... first animation done then the position change but I need to make it simultaneously

Comment: they all start at the same time, maybe your TranslateAnimation has starting offset set?

Comment: I added the code what I m using after EDIT 1. Please have a look on it

Comment: trans.setDuration(2000) and remove AnimationSet

Comment: can you tell me the reson to make the time 2 sec or more than 2

Comment: ok it should be 4 sec since your AnimationDrawable lasts for 4 seconds

Answer (score 0):

This might give you an idea..

```
private void runAnimation(View view){

        ValueAnimator vAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 1,0f);
        vAnimator.setDuration(1000);
        vAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        vAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);

        ValueAnimator vAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 100f);
        vAnimator2.setDuration(1000);
        vAnimator2.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        vAnimator2.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);

        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.playTogether(vAnimator,vAnimator2);
        set.setStartDelay(0);

        set.start();

    }
```

Comment: can I use the AnimationDrawable in ValueAnimator ??

Comment: can you give some more elaboration ?